# POST more information from HTML page (more than input values)

Tags: html, post, content-disposition

I am starting web developement. 
While POSTing a form, all the input fields are sent as properties (Content-Disposition). I would like to add more information (I mean more properties sent by POST), like a value of some html tag, or the value of an attribut of some div. Is this possible ?

Comment: You need to use Javascript to include that in a form element.

Comment: What is your real intention? Most HTML tags have static content – i.e. not changeable by the user. SO everything that occurs in the HTML is also known by your application before filling the templates and setting up the form. If you need to store additional data to be re-posted, use hidden inputs, as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Well an idea to resolve that is to use "hidden input" (@html.HiddenFor). That's what I am going to do waiting for better solution.

Answer (score -1):

What server side technology are you using? You will likely use JavaScript to get other values from your form then submit, but it really just depends. You may want to be more specific.

Comment: I am using ASP MVC 3 on server side. No html decoration is possible to make some div value sendable within a POST ? I am obliged to use Javascript. And how can I do it with javascript ?